# Is there any way to send multiple notes in one call using rest api to salesforce using c#

Tags: c#, rest, salesforce

Using REST API to upload notes to Salesforce, Is there any way to send multiple notes in one go?

eg. we have a Lead with id (xxxxxxxxxxxxx)

Now we want to send two notes in single request.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The native REST API doesn't currently support creating multiple records in one call. Instead you can:

1. Use the Bulk API
2. Use the SOAP API
3. Create your own REST service using @RestResource that accepts a collection